# Laravel Carbon format method unexpected result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I get this date of my database:

```
$ticket = array('date'  => '05-07-16 16:07:14') # day/month/year
```

In my blade.php format this date with Carbon:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($ticket['date'])->format('d-m-Y') }}
```

This returns me -> '16-07-2005'

**But I want this '05-07-16'**

Years and days is not correct. 2016 is the year, and 05 is the day of this month (07).

Why format d-m-Y not works for me?

Answer (score 2):

use createFromFormat method in Carbon

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s:i', $ticket['date'])->format('d-m-Y') }}
```

Comment: this return me this error: ErrorException in Carbon.php line 425:
The format separator does not match
The format separator does not match
The format separator does not match
The format separator does not match
The format separator does not match

Comment: i think it should work now. you see it's parsing  your given date using the 2nd parameter as reference format. so your date format and the format you're using to parse it should match.

Comment: createFromFormat has a different signature - first the format, next the date, so `{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s:i', $ticket['date'])->format('d-m-Y') }}`

Comment: Thanks you @Finwe, but this return me 05-07-0016, Can I get 2016 or the current year?

Comment: i don't think you can do that unless you change 16 to 2016 before even parsing the date to the method. since Carbon does not know which century you're referring  to.

Comment: @FunnyFrontend Try to use `'d-m-y H:s:i'` as a datetime format. See [PHP date formatting options](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).